# Adding MovieClips in a grid to stage based on keyPresses

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Looking to see if anyone can help me out with this before i lose my mind! I am required to add movieclips for each  of the alphabetical keys (a to z) the user  presses on the keyboard, on the stage commencing at the top left corner of the stage proceeding horizontally across the stage towards the right. 
key on  the stage, commencing at the top left corner of the stage and proceeding    horizontally across the stage for each subsequent character. I currently have this code however the movieclips that are entered into a container overlap as the user presses the keys on the keyboard. Help desperately needed!

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
var nextYPos:int = 25;
var i:int = 0;

var A_mc = new AKey();
var B_mc = new BKey();
var C_mc = new CKey();
var D_mc = new DKey();
var E_mc = new EKey();
var F_mc = new FKey();
var G_mc = new GKey();//declare lose movieclip variable
var H_mc = new HKey();
var I_mc = new IKey();
var J_mc = new JKey();
var K_mc = new KKey();
var L_mc = new LKey();
var M_mc = new MKey();//declare lose movieclip variable
var N_mc = new NKey();
var O_mc = new OKey();
var P_mc = new PKey();
var Q_mc = new QKey();
var R_mc = new RKey();
var S_mc = new SKey();//declare lose movieclip variable
var T_mc = new TKey();
var U_mc = new UKey();
var V_mc = new VKey();
var W_mc = new WKey();
var X_mc = new XKey();
var Y_mc = new YKey();
var Z_mc = new ZKey();

var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(container);
container.x = 50;
container.y = 30;
//container.width = 30;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, letters);

function letters(e:KeyboardEvent):void{

    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.A){
            container.addChild(A_mc);
            // A_mc = textinput;
            //A_mc.x = 50;//x value for lose movieclip addChild
            //A_mc.y = 30;//y value for lose movieclip addChild
             A_mc.x = nextYPos;

    }if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.B){
            container.addChild(B_mc);
            //B_mc = textinput;
            //B_mc.x = 75;
            //B_mc.y = 30;
             B_mc.x = nextYPos;


    }if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.C){
            container.addChild(C_mc);
            //C_mc.x = 100;
            //C_mc.y = 30;

    }if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.D){
            container.addChild(D_mc);
            //D_mc.x = 125;
            //D_mc.y = 30;

    }if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.E){
            container.addChild(E_mc);
            //E_mc.x = 150;
            //E_mc.y = 30;

    }if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.F){
            container.addChild(F_mc);
            //F_mc.x = 175;//x value for lose movieclip addChild
            //F_mc.y = 30;//y value for lose movieclip addChild

    }if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.G){
            container.addChild(G_mc);
            //G_mc.x = 195;
            //G_mc.y = 30;

    }if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.H){
            container.addChild(H_mc);
            //H_mc.x = 220;
            //H_mc.y = 30;

    }if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.I){
            container.addChild(I_mc);
            //I_mc.x = 245;
            //I_mc.y = 30;

    }if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.J){
            container.addChild(J_mc);
            //J_mc.x = 255;
            //J_mc.y = 30;

    }if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.K){
            container.addChild(K_mc);
            //K_mc.x = 275;//x value for lose movieclip addChild
            //K_mc.y = 30;//y value for lose movieclip addChild

    }if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.L){
            container.addChild(L_mc);
            //L_mc.x = 300;
            //L_mc.y = 30;

    }if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.M){
            container.addChild(M_mc);
            //M_mc.x = 320;
            //M_mc.y = 30;

    }if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.N){
            container.addChild(N_mc);
            //N_mc.x = 350;
            //N_mc.y = 30;

    }if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.O){
            container.addChild(O_mc);
            //O_mc.x = 375;
            //O_mc.y = 30;

    }if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.P){
            container.addChild(P_mc);
            //P_mc.x = 400;//x value for lose movieclip addChild
            //P_mc.y = 30;//y value for lose movieclip addChild

    }if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.Q){
            container.addChild(Q_mc);
            //Q_mc.x = 50;
            //Q_mc.y = 80;

    }if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.R){
            container.addChild(R_mc);
            //R_mc.x = 75;
            //R_mc.y = 80;

    }if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.S){
            container.addChild(S_mc);
            //S_mc.x = 100;
            //S_mc.y = 80;

    }if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.T){
            container.addChild(T_mc);
            //T_mc.x = 120;
            //T_mc.y = 80;

    }if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.U){
            container.addChild(U_mc);
            //U_mc.x = 140;//x value for lose movieclip addChild
            //U_mc.y = 80;//y value for lose movieclip addChild

    }if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.V){
            container.addChild(V_mc);
            //V_mc.x = 165;
            //V_mc.y = 80;

    }if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.W){
            container.addChild(W_mc);
            //W_mc.x = 190;
            //W_mc.y = 80;

    }if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.X){
            container.addChild(X_mc);
            //X_mc.x = 220;
            //X_mc.y = 80;

    }if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.Y){
            container.addChild(Y_mc);
            //Y_mc.x = 245;
            //Y_mc.y = 80;

    }if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.Z){
        container.addChild(Z_mc);
        //Z_mc.x = 270;
        //Z_mc.y = 80;

    }else {
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand.  You've commented out all the x/y assignments, so all buttons will be at position `0,0`.   Are you wanting something that just distributes all the movie clips in a grid?  This is a whole lot of redundant code here, you could easily make 1 library object with dynamic text field and create all 26 of your keys in a for loop.

Comment: You're not trying to get people to do your homework for you are you?  Your last edit looks suspiciously like a homework assignment.

Comment: No i'm not trying to do that trust me.. just couldnt get that part to work and couldn't wrap my head around why.

Comment: I tested it there, thanks so much, really helped and got me back on track with all the rest ive to do :)

Comment: Glad to help.  Please remember to upvote helpful answers, and accept the most appropriate ones (the green check mark) - You've never accepted an answer for any of your questions, which reflects poorly on your profile and can make some people hesitant to bother reading/answering.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be interpreting your question properly, but it sounds like whenever a letter key is pressed on the keyboard, you want that letter to show up on the screen in a distributed fashion.   In which case, something like this would work in addition to your current code:

```
//any time something new is added to container, call distribute keys
container.addEventListener(Event.ADDED, distributeKeys);

function distributeKeys(e:Event):void {
    var padding:Number = 5; //padding between rows/columns
    var curY:Number = padding; //starting Y
    var curX:Number = padding; //starting X
    var curH:Number = 0; //the current rows tallest item (this is only needed if the height of your clips varies, if each row is a fixed height, then you can take out all references to curH.

    var curKey:DisplayObject; //for storing the current letter clip in the loop below

    //iterate through all the children of container
    for(var i:int=0;i<container.numChildren;i++){
        curKey = container.getChildAt(i);

        curKey.x = curX;

        //if curKey goes past the edge, move it down and left
        if(curKey.x + curKey.width + padding > stage.stageWidth){
            curX = padding; //reset the x coordinate to far left
            curKey.x = curX; //move curKey to the new current X spot

            //if using variable height (curH)
            curY += curH + padding; //increase the row position
            curH = 0; //reset the row height since we just started a new row

            //if using fixed height (every item has the same height) do this:
            // curY += curKey.height + padding;
        }

        curKey.y = curY; //make curKey y go to the current y position
        curX += curKey.width + padding; //increment the current X position
        curH = Math.max(curH, curKey.height); //store the current biggest item in this row, take out this line if using fixed height 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah sorry i'm not very good at explaining what im trying to do.. i uploaded a screenshot there of my requirements. I'm struggling to add the movie clips to the stage progressively across the stage from left to right based on the users key presses.

Comment: That's what I though, the code should work if added to your existing code.  Alternatively, you could just take everything in my `distributeKeys` function and put in at the end of your `letters` function.