# How to align "boxes" in a grid layout

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, menu, grid-layout

I've this little "menu" I'm loading via XML in my .swf

This is my code:

```
for each(var datos: XML in xml.datos) {


    var menuItem: MenuItem = new MenuItem();
    menuItem.x = count * menuItem.height * 6;
    menuItem.y = 0;
    menuItem.menuText.text = datos.@causa;
    menuItem.mouseChildren = false;
    menuItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseOverItem);
    menuItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseOutItem);
    menuItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, itemClicked);
    menuHolder.addChild(menuItem);
    count++;
}
```

That will put every "menu" loaded next to each other (from left to right).

Let's just say I'm loading 30 "boxes" and what I need is to show them like this:

[image]

Comment: So, what is the problem? You forgot to write that part down :)

Comment: With that code, all I do it's to put every "box" next to each other, what I need it's to show 4 per row (for example).

Comment: My answer to this question may help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954603/adding-movieclips-in-a-grid-to-stage-based-on-keypresses/29955844#29955844

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work.  Basically, every time your `count` get's to 5 it resets.  Since your `x` value is based on `count`, it too will be reset and start again from the left.  In addition, your `yPos` will be increased by some value (I chose 50 for example) and the next row will be offset by that amount.

```
var yPos: Number = 0;
for each(var datos: XML in xml.datos) {
    var menuItem: MenuItem = new MenuItem();
    menuItem.x = count * menuItem.height * 6;
    menuItem.y = yPos;
    menuItem.menuText.text = datos.@causa;
    menuItem.mouseChildren = false;
    menuItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseOverItem);
    menuItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseOutItem);
    menuItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, itemClicked);
    menuHolder.addChild(menuItem);
    count++;
    if (count % 5 == 0) {
        count = 0;
        yPos += 50;
    }
}
```

You could also do it without the conditional and the yPos var.

As suggested by @DodgerThud, I made the math a little more sensible based on what you are trying to do.

```
var margin: Number = 5;
var numPerRow: Number = 4;
for each(var datos: XML in xml.datos) {
    var menuItem: MenuItem = new MenuItem();
    menuItem.x = (count % numPerRow) * (menuItem.width + margin);
    menuItem.y = Math.floor(count / numPerRow) * (menuItem.height + margin);
    menuItem.menuText.text = datos.@causa;
    menuItem.mouseChildren = false;
    menuItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseOverItem);
    menuItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseOutItem);
    menuItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, itemClicked);
    menuHolder.addChild(menuItem);
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Suggestion, instead of adding 50 to yPos, add `menuItem.height` + a small margin. Also, the equitation for the x-position should involve `menuItem.width` instead of height:

Comment: @DodgerThud: I agree with both points.  But I was only answering the OP's question.  Good suggestions though.

Comment: Thank you!!! That works! I know it was a silly question, but I couldn't solve it -.-